# Using specific two-page view in PDF

Tags: windows-7

Like a book, when I open it, I see a left page and a right page, but those are pages 2 and 3 of the book. I want to see pages 2-3 at the same time in two-page view, not pages 1 and 2, because page 1 is the title page. This is important for double page illustrations

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

In Adobe Reader, select **View > Page Display > Two Page View**.

Also select **Show Cover Page in Two Page View** or **Show Cover Page During Two-Up**.

[image]